# Cassandra: How to set password before starting Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Enabling password authentication by editing cassandra.yaml works fine for me. I can use `bin/cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra` to login.

I have the following in cassandra.yaml:

```
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
```

What I would like to do is to set the password for user "cassandra" BEFORE I start Cassandra. For obvious security reasons, I do not want to start Cassandra with the default password. Can this be done? How?

I am a total Cassandra newbie using Cassandra 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Don't expose Cassandra to the network before changing the password.  (Note that Cassandra defaults to only listening on localhost.)